Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded when using datalist in React
I'm building a React component that fetches drug data from an FDA API and displays it in a <datalist> for searching. However, I'm encountering a `Maximum call stack size exceeded error when trying to render the component.


const { useState, useEffect }  = React

function App() {
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?count=openfda.brand_name.exact&limit=38647')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
            const drugs = json.results.map((i) => i.term)
            setData(drugs)
            console.log(drugs)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err)
        })
}, [])

return (
    <div>
        <input list='drugs' />
        <datalist id='drugs'>
            {data.map((i) => (
                <option value={i} key={i} />
            ))}
        </datalist>
    </div>
)
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App/>)
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



After the data gets logged, the input box remains unusable for a while. And after sometimes (~5 mins) I get this error:
ERROR Maximum call stack size exceeded 
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at scheduleFibersWithFamiliesRecursively (http://localhost:3000/signal/static/js/bundle.js:30527:31)
    ...

How can I see what's causing the call stack to overflow?

Your snippet appears to work

I ran it in localhost and after 5 mins or so, I got that error.

Are you sure its being triggered by a timeframe and not a particularlly large dataset?  Its possible the API only allows so much in and out and perhaps your request is higher than it allows?  The good news is many of the API services can often offer paid per use services that allow much less hindered data sizes.  Or in other words, sometimes you can just throw money at the problem to fix it.  Another good news element to this is the industry you are talking about is one of the few that just has unlimited money to throw at these types of problems.

Your code seems to be fine , perhaps you need to limit your json response.

I can't limit the json response as I require the entire data in my project. And the datalist seems to be working fine initially, the error pops up after a while.

It is likely due to the fact that the API response contains a very large amount of data. This can sometimes cause issues in rendering components, especially if you try to render a huge number of elements at once.
I made some changes to the code you provided.

Data Limit: Reduced the limit parameter in the API request to 1000. Adjust this based on performance and requirements.

Loading State: Added a loading state to provide user feedback while data is being fetched.

Async/Await: Used async/await syntax for better readability and error handling.


const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const res = await fetch('https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?count=openfda.brand_name.exact&limit=1000');
                const json = await res.json();
                const drugs = json.results.map((i) => i.term);
                setData(drugs);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {loading ? (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <input list='drugs' />
                    <datalist id='drugs'>
                        {data.map((i) => (
                            <option value={i} key={i} />
                        ))}
                    </datalist>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);



I can't limit the json response as I require the entire data in my project. And the datalist seems to be working fine initially, the error only pops up after a while.

I mean, you can try to fetch 1000 first then await some seconds and fetch more, you do not need to fetch all items at the first time. I recommend you use pagination or infinite loading implementation
